# How can I change the character sets of an existing database in SQL and MySQL DBMS?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am managing a website that was created by another programmer. The contents of the web page loads from a DB (MySQL / SQL) - he used JOOMLA for the design. Some special characters were showing on the webpage which are not suppose to be (e toÂ theirÂ st). I want to change the default character set to UTF_8_general_ci on the server (SQL server). Please how can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just log into the server and change the SQL table definitions from there. If you are using cPanel, the option you need to select is MYPhPAdmin. The list of joomla tables will be in there, normally with the prefix jos_

Answer (score 0):

Changing the collation for all tables in a MySQL database can be time consuming depending on how many tables you have.

```
That's why we recommend using the following PHP script for changing the collation for all tables at a time:

<?php

$execute_sql = false;

$host = 'host name';
$username = 'user_name';
$password = 'password';
$dbname = 'databse_name';

$db = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

//$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','Admin@123');
//$select_db = mysql_select_db('friends') or die('database not selected'.mysql_error());

$collation = 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci';
$collationPK = 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin';

$result = $db->query("SET foreign_key_checks = 0");

echo '<div>';

if($execute_sql) $db->query("ALTER DATABASE $dbname $collation");

$result = $db->query("SHOW TABLES");

$count = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $table = $row['Tables_in_'.$dbname];
    if($execute_sql) $db->query("ALTER TABLE $table DEFAULT $collation");
    $result1 = $db->query("SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM $table");

    $alter = '';
    while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        if (preg_match('~char|text|enum|set~', $row1["Type"])) {
            // support a different collation for primary keys
            if ($row1["Key"] == "PRI" || $row1["Key"] == "MUL") {
                $newCollation = $collationPK;
            } else {
                $newCollation = $collation;
            }
            // check if we actually need to change the collation
            $alter .= (strlen($alter)?", \n":" ") . "MODIFY `$row1[Field]` $row1[Type] $newCollation" . ($row1["Null"] ? "" : " NOT NULL") . ($row1["Default"] && $row1["Default"] != "NULL" ? " DEFAULT '$row1[Default]'" : "");
        }
    }
    if(strlen($alter)){
        $sql = "ALTER TABLE $table".$alter.";";
        echo "<div>$sql\n\n</div>";
        $db->query($sql);        
    }
    $count++;
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it is much clearer if the actual commands were stated.

1. To update the character set of just a table within the database. Do the following:

   alter table `books` convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;
2. To change the character set of the datababse that has already been created do the following:

   `set collation_database=utf8_general_ci`
3. You can also look at the character set assigned to each table by doing `show table status \G`